# Hide "Edit Page" menu on customized DispForm.aspx

Tags: 2007, web-part, wss

I have a custom web part (C#) for viewing/editing a SharePoint list, which I have added to the NewForm, DispForm, and EditForm pages for that list. Unfortunately, users with Edit permissions for the list now see the Site Actions menu, with the "Edit Page" submenu. An OOTB list does NOT show the "Edit Page" option for these three pages. Is there a permission setting, or something else I can do to hide the menu again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are already doing some custom code, use CSS to hide the Edit Page button.  (If you aren't sure which class to hide, use the IE Developer Toolbar when viewing the page to select the button and get the class name).